# How to put JSON data to Redux state?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ajax, redux

I have JSON file in my React app, I put it to the folder 'public'. So, how I can  put it's data to Redux state?

```
const initialState = {
   phones: {}, // Json contains a lot of objects
   model: {},
   price: {} //etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your JSON file into some folder like src/data and simply import that file

import data from '../data/somefile.json

then give the data to redux